# How to save and load vector layer attribute value map, editable state in .qml style file?

Tags: qgis, style, qml, qgis-2.4

I just upgraded to Qgis 2.4 and there were problems with style file:

- When I load style file for Qgis <= 2.2, the color of features is
  right but when I edit them, the value map (value - description pair)
  is lost.
- The value map I created for layers in Qgis 2.4 is not
  kept in .qml style file when I choose 'save style' as 'Qgis layer
  style file'.

Is this a bug in Qgis 2.4?

**ADDED INFORMATION:**

Sample files: http://www.mediafire.com/download/bbk02sj3jl9iwtc/test_data.7z

For line layer *line.shp* with 3 attributes: id, name, type - I have style file *2_2_line_style.qml* generated from Qgis 2.2 which have following lines:

```
  <edittypes>
    <edittype labelontop="0" editable="0" type="0" name="id"/>
    <edittype labelontop="0" editable="1" type="0" name="name"/>
    <edittype labelontop="0" editable="1" type="3" name="type">
      <valuepair key="first type" value="1"/>
      <valuepair key="second type" value="2"/>
      <valuepair key="third type" value="3"/>
    </edittype>
  </edittypes>
```

In Qgis 2.2, when I load that line layer with that style and add more lines, there will be a pop up window that allows me to enter values with a drop down list:

[image]

But in Qgis 2.4, when I load the same layer with the style file and add (create new) features, **the drop down list is gone**:

[image]

More over, in Qgis 2.4, when I set the value map for that line layer manually, I can get the drop down list but when I save the style as .qml and inspect the file, there isn't any key - value line like the 2.2 style file.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My apologies for the off-the-record answer. 
For me it seems you have found a bug :-)

I can reproduce your problem and did not find a solution/explanation for it...

[image]

---

*Before* ***ADDED INFORMATION***

Strange, but I don't think it's a bug. In QGIS 2.4 I loaded a vector layer, applied a style by loading a .qml saved in QGIS 2.2, and there were no issues. I made a small change in the value map, saved it as a new .qml and loading it again went smoothly.

If you mention '... when I edit them', do you mean you select another color range from the dropdown menu? Because that's perfectly possible without losing your value-description settings. Just don't click 'Classify' because that will mess up your value map according to the classification mode you selected. But I guess you know all that...

Opening a .qml file in Notepad, you normally should see your value map at the top. Something like:

```
<ranges>
  <range symbol="0" lower="0.000000" upper="12000.000000" label="No data"/>
  <range symbol="1" lower="12000.000000" upper="16000.000000" label="12000 - 16000"/>
  <range symbol="2" lower="16000.000000" upper="21000.000000" label="16000 - 21000"/>
  <range symbol="3" lower="21000.000000" upper="25000.000000" label="21000 - 25000"/>
  <range symbol="4" lower="25000.000000" upper="29000.000000" label="25000 - 29000"/>
</ranges>
```

---

After your comment, this will probably help you further.

IF I understand what you're doing, you try to edit the values map under the Fields tab, and there you find a column called 'Edit Widget'.

[image]

I did not dig out that functionality yet, but assuming you just want to apply a style on a vector layer (nice colors and dito labels), open the Properties window of the vector layer you like to apply a style on, and do as follows.

- If you already have a .qml file, you can load it through 'Load Style ...' **(A)**.
- Check out that the name of the attribute/field (stored in the .qml file) corresponds with an existing attribute in the table of your vector layer. If not, just select from the dropdown menu the column/field/attribute you like to show in your map with your style **(B)**. In the .qml file, you can find the attribute's name in the 3th line:

  ```
  <renderer-v2 attr="FIELD_OF_INTEREST" symbollevels="1" type="graduatedSymbol">
  ```
- If you're still happy with the style you loaded, fine! If not, edit the number of classes, choose a color ramp and a classification mode. If you're not satisfied with the lower and upper values of the generated classes, double-click in the area depicted with the red rectangle **(C)**.
- A small window opens allowing you to adapt the lower and upper values to your wishes **(D)**.
- Finally, you can edit the description of your classes **(E)**. In this example you see the value map of a numerical field, but in case of, for example, a land use map, your value can be an integer code and the description the name of the corresponding land use.
- Click 'OK' to apply the configured style (maybe you can save your style first with 'Save Style').

[image]

[image]

All done, you'll notice that the applied changes (color and value map) will appear as a legend.

[image]

Comment: when opening the qml in notepad, I see the value map, but when loading into qgis the edit widget under the fields tab remains unchanged.

Comment: Reading your comment, and more exactly the anchor points 'fields tab' and 'edit widget', I think I know what your problem is. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to retrieve the value map by saving the QGIS layer stack file (*.qml). When I reloaded the vector layer, I simply load the qml file and voila... value map appears... No problem